# QML - How do create a drag and drop behavior the item of tableview

Tags: qml, tableview, qtquickcontrols

I created a table below using tableview of qt quick control 1.4

[image]

My code is

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QtC1

QtC1.TableView{
            id: tbvScences
            anchors.fill: parent

            ListModel{
                id: lstScences
                ListElement{
                    num: qsTr("1")
                    name: qsTr("on all")
                }
                ListElement{
                    num: qsTr("2")
                    name: qsTr("off all")
                }
            }

            /* Create columns */
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvScences_num
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                role: qsTr("num")
                title: qsTr("Num")
                width: 40
            }
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvScences_Name
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                role: qsTr("name")
                title: qsTr("Name")
                width: 60
            }
            model: lstScences
        }
```

And now, I want to create a dragging and dropping a row to another item with keeping data of source table. Does anyone help me? Your help is my appreciate, many thanks.

Comment: Did you already try to implement that? I see no code for drag'n'drop ...

Comment: I am trying with this link https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html. But I am not still successful. I create a mouse area into tableview, the result is only component to active another is below. Could you give me a few suggestions?

Comment: You have to complement your example, just post the code where you've tried to implement the issue.